# Can't apply Microsoft naming guideline for resource identifiers

Tags: silverlight, resources

I have a Silverlight application with resource files containing strings for localization.

Since there will be a huge number of strings, I was looking for a nice way to create identifiers. So I went to this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229037.aspx) where it is said:

> **Do use the dot separator (".") to nest identifiers with a clear hierarchy.**
>
> For example, names such as Menus.FileMenu.Close.Text and
>   Menus.FileMenu.Close.Color conform to this guideline.

But when I try to use such identifiers (like `Foo.Bar`), Visual Studio keeps telling me that the resource name is not a valid identifier... It's just a warning and doesn't prevent my application from building but then my resources are not found at runtime.
Of course everything is fine if I change the identifiers for simpler ones like `Foo`).

What am I doing wrong? What did I miss in the Microsoft guideline?

Any help, hint or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From here:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/f289ab2a-f22f-45b0-9d9a-78f2b995ee7a)

> Or you can disable generating strongly-typed feature for your .resx
>   file.  To do this, you can select your .resx file in the solution
>   explorer, go to the property page for that file item, set "Custom
>   Tool" and "Custom Tool Namespace" to be empty string.

I tried this and it worked.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed answers my question but if I do this, no code is generated and I can't use Tim Heuer's CustomResources class: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx. Well, maybe I'll just replace the `.` with some `_`...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Where are these generated properties? How can I access them from XAML through databinding?

Comment: See this: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx

Comment: I know this article. It's the one I cite in my question. :o) But this doesn't work. The only way to have dots in resource identifiers is to set the "Access modifier" of the resource files to "No code generation". But then, I can't figure out how to bind my resource strings in the XAML (but it's OK in the C# code).

Comment: I don't see a reference in the question to the article. To be honest: I'd skip the guidelines and use names without dots. The guides are there to help you not to stress you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "in my first comment". ;o) And of course, I agree with you about the role of the guidelines in general but this one, I found useful to achieve better clarity. Anyway, thank you for your time.